# BackupExec errors when starting services

Tags: backupexec

I've installed backupexec 2010 trial on my server, with an appropriately-privileged AD account, but get errors when starting the required services from the login page:

Processing services

Start services on server: WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ
Starting Enterprise Vault Admin Service on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
The service Enterprise Vault Admin Service is already running on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
Starting Backup Exec Remote Agent for Windows Systems on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
The service Backup Exec Remote Agent for Windows Systems is already running on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
Starting Backup Exec Device & Media Service on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
Error starting the service Backup Exec Device & Media Service on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ. Service-specific error code returned: 
0x2000e2d3 (536928979)

Starting Backup Exec Server on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
Error starting the service Backup Exec Server on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
The dependency service or group failed to start.

Starting Backup Exec Job Engine on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
Error starting the service Backup Exec Job Engine on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
The dependency service or group failed to start.

Starting Backup Exec Agent Browser on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
Error starting the service Backup Exec Agent Browser on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
The dependency service or group failed to start.

Starting Backup Exec DLO Administration Service on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
Error starting the service Backup Exec DLO Administration Service on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.  Error code returned:

Starting Backup Exec DLO Maintenance Service on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
The service Backup Exec DLO Maintenance Service is already running on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
Starting Backup Exec Web Service on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
The service Backup Exec Web Service is already running on WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ.
Start services on server WIN-HQ7JSCRTTSQ completed.

Processing services completed!

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Installing BackupAssist or some other non-Symantec product would be an excellent start.

Comment: You should be able to get support with Symantec for your trial, that is if they want you to buy it :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest patches and restart the server once.

Answer (score 0):

http://seer.entsupport.symantec.com/docs/302729.htm

Is SQL Express installed and running?

Comment: I'm using a Sql Server 2008 instance, and I've added the AD account I created to the instance the BEDB database. The SQL Server service is running and accessible (no issue with SQL Server in the installation, either).